# How to work with FilterActivity via SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, filters, fuel

I have some issues when I try to create a FilterActivity via API.

In the Marketing Cloud I usually define a DataFilter, then from Interactions I create a Filter having that DataFilter as FilterDefinition and a result DataExtension. Then I go to the Automation Studio and create an automation in which the first activity is the interaction Filter that I defined earlier.

Now I need to do the same thing via API.

I managed to create a FilterDefinition. The first issue is that I was not able to create a SimpleFilterPart in which a date is compared to 'TodayPlus 10 Days'. It works fine when comparing with 'Today'. What value should I pass to the SimpleFilterPart so that my Date filed is compared to 'TodayPlus 10 Days'?

Then I created the destination DataExtension. I retrieved the source DE, the destination DE, the FilterDefinition and tried to create the FilterActivity.
But the response is 'Invalid DestinationTypeID'. 
What value should this field have so that the FilterActivity is successfully created?

Assuming that I already have the interaction filter, I tried to retrieve it so that I can use it in the automation. I used a RetrieveRequest for ObjectType = 'FilterActivity' with a SimpleFilter to identify the object by name. In the response I get the following error 'Error: No view defined for the object type: FilterActivity'. 
How should I retrieve a FilterActivity?

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give with any of these issues.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to guess this is about the Fuel API ? May be useful to include that in your subject/title.

Comment: I'm using the Soap API. I edited the title. Thank you!